# How to get all running services in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How can I get a list of all services installed on  the system with their current status? I am not looking for the list of processes using `Process` class in C#, I am looking for the services.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From link [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/windows-service-list/):

> To get list of all services (which are not device drivers) use static method [ServiceContro­ller.GetServi­ces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (to get list of `driver services` use method [ServiceContro­ller.GetDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5sy3z2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
```

You can get the status for all services in a dictionary like this:

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
var servicesStatus = services.ToDictionary(s => s.ServiceName, s => s.Status);
```